R Crosstalk Interactivity
I want to create interactive visualizations using R cross talk. I am using ggplot to create 2 graphs from the data set.
Sample data Set
Let's say this is my sample dataset.
So, I want a drop-down menu with options A, B, C that lets me choose what facilities I want to view. Now I want two graphs - heatmaps. One with test D and E (Graph 1) and one with F and G (Graph 2) both affected by 1 single drop down i.e. one filter_select.
The description of the graphs are as follows.
Graph 1. It has month on the X axis, E and D on Y axis, the value at (E,1) is the numeric value that decides the color of the heat map. That's the same for ED-1234.
The SharedData instance for this has the rows where Test is E and D.
Graph 2. It has month on the X axis, G and F on Y axis, the value at (G,1) is the numeric value that decides the color of the heat map. That's the same for GF-1234.
The SharedData instance for this has the rows where Test is G and F.
I have tried 2 approaches:
Approach 1: Have separate ShareData Instances for both the graphs.
Look at Code Approach 1
So, if we have this dropdown, graph 2 won't change when we make choices on dropdown from the SharedData1 instance. I would need to add another filter_select drop down for graph 2 but that would not affect graph 1 since they are two shared data instances.
Approach 2: Using single SharedData instance for both graphs
Look at Code Approach 2
I get the error:
"no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "c('SharedData', 'R6')"
I cannot use Rshiny since I do not have servers. I am planning to embed this in a self-contained HTML"
Code for Data Set
data=data.frame(
  Facility=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"),
  Test=c("D","E","F","G","D","E","F","G","D","E","F","G"),
  Month=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
  Numeric=c(0.74, 0.58, 0.86, 0.09, 0.24, 0.14, 1.19, 0.66, 1.12,   1.14, 1.34, 1.53)
)

Code Approach 1:
SharedDataInstance_1=SharedData$new(data %>% filter(Test %in% c("D","E")) filter_select(id="facilities",
                            label="Choose facilities Graph 1",sharedData = data_graph1, group=~Facility) SharedDataInstance_2=SharedData$new(data %>% filter(Test %in% c("F","G")) filter_select(id="facilities",
                           label="Choose facilities graph 2",sharedData = data_graph2, group=~Facility)

graph1=SharedDataInstance_1%>%
         ggplot(aes(month,Test,fill=factor(Numeric)))+
         labs(x="Month",y="Tests",fill="Error Legend")+
         geom_tile(color='white',linewidth =3)+
         facet_wrap(~Facility)

graph2=SharedDataInstance_2%>%
         ggplot(aes(month,Test,fill=factor(Numeric)))+
         labs(x="Month",y="Tests",fill="Error Legend")+
         geom_tile(color='white',linewidth =3) +
         facet_wrap(~Facility)


Code Approach 2:
SharedDataInstance_12=SharedData$new(data) filter_select(id="facilities",
                                     label="Choosefacilities",sharedData = data_graph, group=~Facility) 

graph1=SharedDataInstance_12 %>%      
          filter(Test %in% c("D","E") %>%      
          ggplot()+
          labs(x="Month",y="Tests",fill="Error Legend")+
          geom_tile(color='white',linewidth =3)+
          facet_wrap(~Facility)

graph2=SharedDataInstance_12 %>%      
          filter(Test %in% c("F","G") %>%      
          ggplot()+
          labs(x="Month",y="Tests",fill="Error Legend")+
          geom_tile(color='white',linewidth =3)+
          facet_wrap(~Facility)


